# How to print "hello world" from a C++/MFC dialog application to a specific printer

Tags: c++, printing, mfc

I want to skip the fancy stuff and do the simplest possible thing: print "hello world!" to a pre-specified printer (no dialogs or user interaction allowed). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798307/printing-to-a-printer-dc-with-mfc) and its answers seem to have everything else I need... but I fail at the first step: how do I actually specify the parameters to the `CreateDC()` function? I'm confident in the printer device name, but not the driver name - where can I find a definitive answer?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490.aspx): *"A pointer to a null-terminated character string that specifies either DISPLAY or the name of a specific display device. **For printing, we recommend that you pass `NULL` to lpszDriver because GDI ignores lpszDriver for printer devices**."*

Comment: I had read that, then also read conflicting info somewhere else, so returned to trying to find an explicit driver name. But thanks: it works :-) Meanwhile, I got `EnumPrinters()` to work, and found the missing char in the driver name that the Windows Test Page was printing off the edge of the sheet. Either method works for me - explicit driver or NULL.